# Replace multidimensional rows with key-value pairs from each of its leafnodes

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, flatten

I want to flatten an array of row -- each with variable depth -- so that it becomes an array of associative arrays.

I tried some very good examples over here that works for associative or multi dimensional arrays but couldn't put them together in a good use to solve my problem:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [level2_1] => aa
            [level2_2] => bb
            [level2_3] => cc
            [level2_4] => Array
                (
                    [level3_1] => DDD
                    [level3_2] => EEE
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [level2_1] => ff
            [level2_2] => gg
            [level2_3] => hh
            [level2_4] => Array
                (
                    [level3_1] => III
                    [level3_2] => JJJ
                )

        )

)
```

**Expected output:**

```
0 -> level2_1: aa, level2_2: bb, level2_3: cc, level3_1: DDD, level3_2: EEE
1 -> level2_1: ff, level2_2: gg, level2_3: hh, level3_1: III, level3_2: JJJ
```

**Or At Least:**

```
0: aa, bb, cc, DDD, EEE
1: ff, gg, hh, III, JJJ
```

I tried many non-loop answers regarding **implode, multi-dimension**, etc.
I think they need some modification if one of the element (level2_4) is array instead of string, flatten its elements.

Here are some good samples of code I found working but needs to be modified to fit my case:

> **# Basic but stops at a sub-array:**
>
> echo implode(',', call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data));
>
> **# PHP implode associative array:**
>
> implode(', ', array_map(function ($k, $v) { return "$k: $v"; }, array_keys($data), array_values($data)));
>
> **# PHP implode multi dimensional array:**
>
> $result[0][code] = "123";
>
> $result[0][desc] = "Desc123";
>
> $result[1][code] = "567";
>
> $result[1][desc] = "Desc567";
>
> echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($k, $v) { return "$k: $v"; }, array_keys(array_column($result, 'desc', 'code')), array_values(array_column($result, 'desc', 'code'))));

Comment: How about `$str='';
array_walk_recursive($x, function($v,$k) use (&$str) {$str.=$k.': '.$v.', ';});`, where `$x` is your array. Might need some trimming, but looks close.

Comment: @jh1711 **Very close!** Why don't you make up the new lines 0 ->, 1->, .. on level1 arrays ([0], [1], [2], ...) and post an answer?

Comment: No need to have competing answers that are almost the same. Roman solved trailing commas, and getting the $key -> $value format. That's why I voted his answer. For the new lines: see my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With combination of `array_keys` + `array_walk_recursive` + `array_map` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$result = array_map(function($k) use($arr){
    $s = "$k ->";   // key prefix
    array_walk_recursive($arr[$k], function($v, $k) use(&$s){
        $s .= " $k: $v,";
    });
    return trim($s, ',');
}, array_keys($arr));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0 -> level2_1: aa, level2_2: bb, level2_3: cc, level3_1: DDD, level3_2: EEE
    [1] => 1 -> level2_1: ff, level2_2: gg, level2_3: hh, level3_1: III, level3_2: JJJ
)
```

Comment: Maybe `$result = implode("\n", array_map(...` to get the exact output. Of course you need to lose the line breaks. Way to readable ;)

Comment: With the final implode from the comment of @jh1711, it works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much there but for the trailing commas.

```
<?php

$data =
[
        [
            'level2_1' => 'aa',
            'level2_2' => 'bb',
            'level2_3' => 'cc',
            'level2_4' =>
                [
                    'level3_1' => 'DDD',
                    'level3_2' => 'EEE'
                ]
         ],
         [
            'level2_1' => 'ff',
            'level2_2' => 'gg',
            'level2_3' => 'hh',
            'level2_4' =>
                [
                    'level3_1' => 'III',
                    'level3_2' => 'JJJ'
                ]
        ]
];  

array_walk($data, function($v, $k) {
    print "$k ->";
    array_walk_recursive($v, function($v, $k) {
        printf(' %s: %s,', $k, $v);
    });
    print "\n";
});
```

Output:

```
0 -> level2_1: aa, level2_2: bb, level2_3: cc, level3_1: DDD, level3_2: EEE,
1 -> level2_1: ff, level2_2: gg, level2_3: hh, level3_1: III, level3_2: JJJ,
```

And to fix the trailing commas swap the printf line to:

```
print rtrim(sprintf(' %s: %s,', $k, $v),',');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can try a different way like this:

```
<?php
function Recursive($data){
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
$result = array();
foreach ($ritit as $leafValue) {
$keys = array();
foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()) as $depth) {
$keys[] = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
}
$result[ join('.', $keys) ] = $leafValue;
}
return $result;
}

$data =
[
        [
            'level2_1' => 'aa',
            'level2_2' => 'bb',
            'level2_3' => 'cc',
            'level2_4' =>
                [
                    'level3_1' => 'DDD',
                    'level3_2' => 'EEE'
                ]
         ],
         [
            'level2_1' => 'ff',
            'level2_2' => 'gg',
            'level2_3' => 'hh',
            'level2_4' =>
                [
                    'level3_1' => 'III',
                    'level3_2' => 'JJJ'
                ]
        ]
];  

$recursive = Recursive($data);
echo "<pre>".print_r($recursive,1)."<pre>";
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0.level2_1] => aa
    [0.level2_2] => bb
    [0.level2_3] => cc
    [0.level2_4.level3_1] => DDD
    [0.level2_4.level3_2] => EEE
    [1.level2_1] => ff
    [1.level2_2] => gg
    [1.level2_3] => hh
    [1.level2_4.level3_1] => III
    [1.level2_4.level3_2] => JJJ
)
```

Comment: OP says: "without using any loops" I interpret that as meaning no for/foreach/while loops (control structures) or in other words only use functional iterators.